# Unable to connect Tableau Desktop to Oracle Autonomous JSON Database

Tags: oracle, tableau-desktop, oracle-autonomous-db

I've been trying various methods to establish a connection between Tableau Desktop and Oracle Autonomous JSON Database, but unfortunately, none of them have been successful so far. I'm seeking assistance to find a working solution for my setup.

I am using Tableau 2023.2 and attempting to connect to an Oracle Autonomous JSON Database. I have tried the following approaches:

https://www.oracle.com/a/ocom/docs/database/adw-connection-instructions-tableau-desktop.pdf
https://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/connecting-to-oracle-autonomous-data-warehouse-using-jdbc

After I followed the first link steps I got this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ztwN.jpg)

and after I followed the second link steps I got this [message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8OB2.jpg)

Despite my efforts, I have not been able to establish a successful connection. I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to connect Tableau Desktop to Oracle Autonomous JSON Database effectively.

If anyone has successfully connected Tableau Desktop to Oracle Autonomous JSON Database or has insights into resolving this issue, I would greatly appreciate your assistance. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: what happens when you try? Share error messages, etc.

Comment: Please add the text of the errors, not redacted pictures of the errors, it makes helping you so much harder

Comment: FAB9A2C5 and D84EA4A5